# Shared Regex patterns across platforms

Tags: regex, cross-platform

We are attempting to share our RegEx-patterns across multiple platforms (Apps (Android/iOS), Web (javascript) and back-end services (C#)).

One problem I forsee is that all of the platforms have different regex engines. Potentially leading to one of them handling the regexp patterns incorrectly.

The regex patterns are originally defined in C#, and then later exposed via Webservice or Bower to the other platforms. Is there anyway to write a unit test for the pattern to ensure that it will work in the other platforms?

The reason I ask that question is because I assume that there is a common regex language and that each engine has it's own unique quirks on top of it. If so it should be possible to verify that each patterns adheres to the commonly understood language.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest choosing the standard that supports the least number of regex features as a base one, that is **Javascript**.

That said, [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) lists what is available in JavaScript:

- Only `g`, `i`, `m` flags, no inline flags are supported
- Backslashes are escaped in JavaScript
- Instead of `(?s)` modifier, use `[\s\S]`
- No `\A` or `\Z` anchors to match the start or end of the string. Use a caret or dollar instead.
- Lookbehind is not supported at all. Lookahead is fully supported.
- No atomic grouping or possessive quantifiers.
- No Unicode support, except for matching single characters with `\uFFFF`.
- No named capturing groups. Use numbered capturing groups instead.
- No mode modifiers to set matching options within the regular expression.
- No conditionals.
- No regular expression comments. Describe your regular expression with JavaScript `//` comments instead, outside the regular expression string.

Also, use unambiguous escaping inside character classes (that is for `-`, `]` and `[` characters mainly, they must be escaped to avoid confusion).

Mind that in Java regex strings, backslashes will have to be double-escaped.

As @nhahdth mentions, avoid using shorthand classes, use character classes instead. `\w` can turn out a real culprit when it comes to matching Unicode letters when you do not need it, and it is safe to just mention you need `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` instead.

Comment: Beware of the differences between `\w`, `\s`, `.`, `\d` between the different flavors. In C#, the shorthand `\w` and `\d` recognize Unicode characters, while in JavaScript, `\w` and `\d` only matches ASCII characters.